# Difference between formation and production

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, pair-production

What's the difference between formation and production processes, e.q. for p-pbar seen on [processes](https://www.google.de/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiRq4_PsPzUAhUPbVAKHavqDR4QjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fslideplayer.com%2Fslide%2F3387472%2F&psig=AFQjCNHk_WFgHz3UBskMN7nF15WmoAJ2Mw&ust=1499695814318836) ?

I know that in production are more final states available than in formation processes. But what exactly is the difference? 
Furthermore the final states depend in both cases on the incident particles, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you give is not easy to understand what the two terms used mean. Seems to me it is a particular usage  by the  physicist who owns the site.

The word "production" is easy,  means just that " a psi is produced in the interaction" as in "producion crossection of psi in p p_bar scattering".

Formation I can see used as in "formation of resonances" in [e+e- hadronic](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/hadronic-xsections/rpp2014-sigma_R_ee_plots.pdf) crossection versus energy, although it is not everyday usage.

[image: e+e-]

In my examples, the differnce is that the total energy of the interaction appears in the formations experiment, whereas in production experiments only part of the energy of the total interaction is taken , as in producing the psi in a p p_bar interaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already wondered that I didn't find much about these terms. I'm not sure if I understood you correctly: In Formation all the energy is used to create a specific particle or resonance and in production just a part of it to create this specific particle?

Comment: Look at the plot . It shows formation experiments. All the energy of e+e- goes to the resonance at the energy around the resonance once it couples. The percentage of events changes as the energy scans the resonance, that is due to the scattering probability, but each even has the total energy of the experiment.